# In Django Rest framework how to achive fetch and update record in single api call

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to fetch one record with status NEW and update the status 'INPROGRESS' in single api call how can I achive this?

**model.py**

```
class Task(models.Model):
    task= models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=200,null=False)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    remark=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    create_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    create_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    update_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    update_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
```

**view.py**

```
class TaskViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Task.objects.filter(status='NEW')[:1];
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

Answer (score 0):

Django rest framework's `modelviewset` provides separate functions for each view type, like list view, detail view etc. You can just override one of them to modify it's functionality. I think for updating just one field of a record you don't have to use a serializer. [Take a look](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/):

```
class TaskViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """
    Example empty viewset demonstrating the standard
    actions that will be handled by a router class.

    If you're using format suffixes, make sure to also include
    the `format=None` keyword argument for each action.
    """

    def list(self, request):
        pass

    def create(self, request):
        pass

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        pass
```

*(Don't forget that modelviewset generates separate api endpoints for each CRUD operation like: create, read, update, delete, detail)*

As you can see here we have preffered function for any type of action. So You can just do whatever you want by getting required record by `pk` parameter, and after completing a process with this one, do whatever you want with the second one by getting it through some relation field of the object you have processed, or by some get parameter coming with the request in case it's not connected by relation field to the object:

call:

```
request.get('/api/endpoint/update/pk=222?second_object_id=23')
```

I'll give you an example of how you can achive this in your update api endpoint.

You view:

```
class TaskViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        # get the main objects and modify
        object = Task.objects.get(pk=pk)
        object.status = 'NEW'
        object.save()
        
        # get second object with the id given in get parameter
        second_object = Task.objects.get(pk=request.GET.get('second_object_id'))
        second_object.status = 'INPROCESS'
        second_object.save()
        return Response({"suceess": True}) # or whatever
```

If you find it difficult to understand my answer, feel free to comment below.